# Is is possible to Download pdf file through pure html?

Tags: html, pdf, download

I'm using link tag to open a pdf file. when clicking that link, the pdf file is opened directly. Is it possible to donwload and save the pdf file to my system through html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is **no**: PDF handling depends entirely on client side software, from web browser to PDF reader. Your server can provide hints that can be used by the browser (or not) but you won't accomplish it with plain HTML.

Whatever, you can probably configure your web server to send appropriate HTTP headers. If you are using **Apache**, you can use an **.htaccess** file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/pdf
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

If you replace **application/pdf** with **application/octet-stream** you *might* even bypass the PDF plug-in if installed (not guaranteed though).

Other web servers will require different config.

Comment: I'm using aspnet. Shall I add in web.config ?

Answer (score 3):

You should change the headers sent to client by server and add something like.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"
```

It can be done with proxy php script or by configuring your webserver.

Comment: Good job mentioning the `filename`. It is so annoying when an HTTP request to a URL like e.g. `http://example.com/download.php?stuff.pdf` pops up a "Save As" dialog wanting to save the downloaded PDF file as `download.php`. Please *do* send a `filename=stuff.pdf` in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot force** this behaviour using plain html only.

The server needs to send a `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=x.pdf` header to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Chrome and Firefox, works like a charm !

`<a href="./directory/yourfile.pdf" download="newfilename">Download the pdf</a>`

Where newfilename is the suggested filename for the user to save the file. Or it will default to the filename on the serverside if you leave it empty, like this:

`<a href="./directory/yourfile.pdf" download>Download the pdf</a>`

Comment: Are you sure you can download a pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you cand do it from HTML ... this is done via headers,
you can modify them either in the backend language or via apache headers

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Alvaro's tip posted a few different places around the web

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/pdf
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

but for some reason when i add this to an .htaccess file I get an internal server error 500.  anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

UPDATE: figured this out - you need to have apache's headers module installed:

```
# a2enmod headers
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but it's worth mentioning that many modern browsers now support the `download` attribute for links, which can be used like this:

```
<a href="/path/to/mydownload.pdf" download>
```